# Wrong return for Sum of nodes on the longest path from root to leaf node

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [Sum of nodes on the longest path from root to leaf node](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sum-of-the-longest-bloodline-of-a-tree/1):

> Given a binary tree of size **N**. Your task is to complete the function `sumOfLongRootToLeafPath()`, that find the sum of all nodes on the longest path from root to leaf node.
>
> If two or more paths compete for the longest path, then the path having maximum sum of nodes is being considered.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
>         4        
>        / \       
>       2   5      
>      / \ / \     
>     7  1 2  3    
>       /
>      6
> ```
>
> **Output:** 13
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> ```
>         4        
>        / \       
>       2   5      
>      / \ / \     
>     7  1 2  3 
>       /
>      6
> ```
>
> The highlighted nodes **(4, 2, 1, 6)** above are
> part of the longest root to leaf path having
> sum = (4 + 2 + 1 + 6) = 13

Here is the code I am trying with:

```
class Solution
{
    class Info
    {
        int count;
        int sum;
        Info(int count,int sum)
        {
            this.count=count;
            this.sum=sum;
        }
    }
    
    public Info findSum(Node root,Info ans)
    {
        if(root==null)
        {
            ans.count=0;
            ans.sum=0;
           
            return ans;
        }
        
        Info l=findSum(root.left,ans);
        Info r=findSum(root.right,ans);
        
        //System.out.println(l.count + " " + l.sum+"     "+r.count+" "+ r.sum);
         
        if(l.count>r.count)
        {
            ans.count=l.count+1;
            ans.sum=l.sum+root.data;
        }
        else if(l.count<r.count)
        {
            ans.count=r.count+1;
            ans.sum=r.sum+root.data;
        }
        else
        {
            ans.count=l.count+1;
            ans.sum=Math.max(l.sum,r.sum)+root.data;
        }
        // System.out.println(ans.count+" "+ans.sum);
        // System.out.println();
        //System.out.println();
        return ans;
        
    }
    public int sumOfLongRootToLeafPath(Node root)
    {
        if(root==null )
        return 0;
        
        Info ans=new Info(0,0);
        return findSum(root,ans).sum;
    }
}
```

For the quoted test case it produces 12 instead of 13.

I've dry runned it many times and can't find any error in the logic... While testing it out by printing the values of `l.count`, `l.sum`, `r.count` ... during the execution, there is something wrong as the values of `l` and `r` are always the same. I think while backtracking the `ans` at left subtree is getting messed up.. somehow.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have one `ans` object, which is written to by all executions of the function, even after a potential optimal solution was already written in it. It just gets overwritten again by less optimal solutions (even set to zeroes at the next visited leaf). This also means that when you have made the two recursive calls, both `l` and `r` are identical: they are identical to `ans`. This is of course not what you intended.

The way you use `ans` as a write-only parameter is not useful, since you also *return* that object. You might as well not have that parameter at all.

Instead, have the base case *create* a new `Info` instance, so that `l` and `r` will be distinct objects, and then decide which of the two is "best", and then upgrade that one with the current node's data and return *that* object.

Here is your code corrected with that idea:

```
class Solution
{
    class Info
    {
        int count;
        int sum;
        
        Info(int count, int sum)
        {
            this.count = count;
            this.sum = sum;
        }
    }
    
    public Info findSum(Node root) // No extra argument
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return new Info(0, 0); // New, distinct instance!
        }
        
        Info l = findSum(root.left);
        Info r = findSum(root.right);
        
        // Select the "best" one
        if (l.count > r.count || l.count == r.count && l.sum > r.sum)
        {
            r = l;
        }
        // Upgrade it to take into account the current node
        r.count++;
        r.sum += root.data;
        return r;
        
    }
    
    public int sumOfLongRootToLeafPath(Node root)
    {
        return findSum(root).sum;
    }
}
```